# Using JSON RPC in Struts2 along with Spring Security causes the request to be forbidden(403)

Tags: json, spring, struts2, spring-security, json-rpc

I use the following JavaScript/jQuery function to make a remote procedure call through JSON.

```
<s:url var="testJsonUrl" action="testJsonAction"/>
<script src="../js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

var timeout;
var request;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#countryComboBox").change(function(){
        if(!request)
        {
            request = $.ajax({
                datatype:"json",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({jsonrpc:'2.0', method:'getStateTables', id:'jsonrpc', params:[$("#countryComboBox").val()]}),
                contentType: "application/json-rpc; charset=utf-8",
                url: "<s:property value='#testJsonUrl'/>",
                success: function(response)
                {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(response.result));
                },
                complete: function()
                {
                    timeout = request = null;
                },
                error: function(request, status, error)
                {
                    if(status!=="timeout"&&status!=="abort")
                    {
                        alert(status+" : "+error);
                    }
                }
            });
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                if(request)
                {
                    request.abort();
                    alert("The request has been timed out.");
                }
            }, 30000);
        }
    });
});
```

This function invokes the method `getStateTables()` in an action class which is as follows.

```
@Namespace("/admin_side")
@ResultPath("/WEB-INF/content")
@ParentPackage(value = "json-default")
public final class TestAction extends ActionSupport
{
    @Autowired
    private final transient SharableService sharableService = null;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    List<StateTable> stateTables;

    public TestAction() {}

    @SMDMethod
    public List<StateTable> getStateTables(@SMDMethodParameter(name="countryId")Long countryId) {
        stateTables = sharableService.findStatesByCountryId(countryId);
        return stateTables;
    }

    @Action(value = "testJsonAction",
    results = {
        @Result(name = ActionSupport.SUCCESS, type = "json", params = {"enableSMD", "true"})},
    interceptorRefs = {
        @InterceptorRef(value = "json", params = {"enableSMD", "true", "includeProperties", "result\\[\\d+\\]\\.stateId, result\\[\\d+\\]\\.stateName", "excludeNullProperties", "true"})})
    public String executeAction() throws Exception {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Action(value = "Test",
    results = {
        @Result(name = ActionSupport.SUCCESS, location = "Test.jsp"),
        @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Test.jsp")},
    interceptorRefs = {
        @InterceptorRef(value = "defaultStack", params = {"params.acceptParamNames", "", "params.excludeMethods", "load", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"})})
    public String load() throws Exception {
        //This method is just used to return an initial view on page load.
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

This method causes a list of states corresponding to the `countryId` supplied by the jQuery function as a parameter to this method to be returned which is delegated to the jQuery function as a JSON response.

This works fine unless Spring Security comes into picture. While using Spring Security, the request is forbidden.

The header information can be viewed as follows.

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/TestStruts/admin_side/testJsonAction.action
Request Method:POST
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Request Headers
    Accept:*/*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
    Cache-Control:max-age=0
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:73
    Content-Type:application/json-rpc; charset=UTF-8
    Cookie:JSESSIONID=0C4D7DFD269F1D5F7315A39971A75961; sbOverlayID=42887237
    Host:localhost:8080
    Origin:http://localhost:8080
    Referer:http://localhost:8080/TestStruts/admin_side/Test.action
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36
    X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
    {jsonrpc:2.0, method:getStateTables, id:jsonrpc, params:[2]}
    id: "jsonrpc"
    jsonrpc: "2.0"
    method: "getStateTables"
    params: [2]
Response Headers
    Content-Length:1149
    Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
    Date:Tue, 28 Jan 2014 22:12:55 GMT
    Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
    X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
    X-Frame-Options:DENY
    X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

My Spring Security configurations are exactly the same as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20919913/1391249) question.

Where to look into Spring Security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something. It is because I'm using a CSRF token (configured in the `spring-security.xml` file as `<csrf/>`) which is required to be sent along with the AJAX request. it worked, when I used a jQuery function along with `<meta>` tags as mentioned [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax).

> If you using JSON, then it is not possible to submit the CSRF token
>   within an HTTP parameter. Instead you can submit the token within a
>   HTTP header. A typical pattern would be to include the CSRF token
>   within your meta tags. An example with a JSP is shown below:
>
> ```
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
>     <!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
>     <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
>     <!-- ... -->
>   </head>
>   <!-- ... -->
> ```
>
> You can then include the token within all your Ajax requests. If you
>   were using jQuery, this could be done with the following:
>
> ```
> $(function () {
>   var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
>   var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
>   $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
>     xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
>   });
> });
> ```